# how to make a Vertical menu bar in Buycraft

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a vertical menu bar on the left of the buycraft shop, however I sadly do not know the css for this, I would appreciate help. The menu bar should look something like [this](http://buy.arkhamnetwork.org/)

This is to be used for a 'Buycraft' shop page.
My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>{{ store.name }} | {{ page.title }}</title>

    <link href="/templates/209/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/templates/209/img/favicon.ico">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36735942-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        
        {% if store.googleAnalytics %}
            _gaq.push(['b._setAccount', '{{ store.googleAnalytics }}']);
            _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);
        {% endif %}
        
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
    
    <style>{{ store.css|raw }}</style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="header">

        <div class="logo">
            {% if store.logo %}
                <a href="/"><img src="{{ store.logo }}" /></a>
            {% else %}
                <span>{{ store.name }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="toolbar">
            <div class="logout">
                {% if basket.username %} 
                    <a href="/checkout/logout" class="btn btn-danger">{{ lang("button.logout") }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="currency">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{ basket.currency }} <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                {% for currency in store.currencies %}
                    {% if currency.code in [store.currency, "AUD", "BRL", "CAD", "DKK", "EUR", "NOK", "NZD", "GBP", "SEK", "USD", "PLN"] %}
                        <li {% if basket.currency == currency.code %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                          <a href="?currency={{ currency.code }}">{{ currency.code }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="basket">
                {% if basket.packages|length > 0 %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    {{ lang("basket.count", basket.packages|length, basket.price|money, basket.currency) }} <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                        {% for package in basket.packages %}
                            <li class="item">
                            <div class="name">{{ package.name[:25] }}</div>
                            <div class="price">{{ package.price|money }} <small>{{ basket.currency }}</small></div>
                            <div class="remove"><a href="/checkout/packages/remove/{{ package.id }}"><span class="fa fa-times"</span></a></div>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <li class="checkout">
                          <div class="total"><b>{{ lang("basket.total") }}:</b> {{ basket.price|money }} <small>{{ basket.currency }}</small></div>
                          <div class="button"><a href="/checkout/basket" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</a></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" disabled="disabled"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> {{ lang("basket.count", 0, 0.00, basket.currency) }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div> 
        
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{ store.name }}</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="{% if page.category == "index" %}active{% endif %}"><a href="/">{{ lang("category.home") }}</a></li>
                {% for category in store.categories %}
                  {% if category.subcategories|length > 0 %}
                    <li class="dropdown {% if category.active %}active{% endif %}">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          {% for subcategory in category.subcategories %}
                            <li><a href="/category/{{ subcategory.id }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</a></li>
                          {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                  {% else %}
                    <li class="{% if category.active %}active{% endif %}"><a href="/category/{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if basket.packages|length > 0 %} 
                    <li class="visible-xs {% if page.category == "checkout" %}active{% endif %}"><a href="/checkout/basket">Checkout</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% if basket.username %} 
                    <li class="visible-xs"><a href="/checkout/logout">Logout</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
        
      <div class="notification">
        {% if page.message.display %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ page.message.type}} alert-dismissable">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                {{ page.message.text }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}  
      </div>

      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

      {% if store.plan == "1" %}
        <div class="advertisement">
            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9830135219921132" data-ad-slot="7404819681"></ins>
            <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      <div class="footer">
          <div class="language">
              <div class="dropdown dropup">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="fa fa-globe"></span> Language</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu up">
                  {% for language in store.languages %}
                      <li><a href="?lang={{ language.code }}">{{ language.name }}</a></li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          {% if store.branding or store.plan != "3" %}
            <div class="branding"> 
              <!-- Do not remove the Buycraft branding if you are not on the Ultimate Plan. Your account will be deleted. -->
              Powered by <a href="http://buycraft.net" target="_blank">Buycraft.net</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal" id="popup-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
    
    {% if page.category == "checkout" %}
      <script src="https://wallet.google.com/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
      <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    {% endif %}
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="/templates/209/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/templates/209/js/skin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/templates/209/js/site.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
<style>
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}
    
</style>
```

Comment: The menu is a simple `ul` filled with elements. Every sub menu is another `ul` inside a `li` that gets shown once you click on a item. The styling is up to, there's nothing special needed for the functionality. And keep in mind, that the snippet can't use your server code ;)

Comment: @Felix Hi, I am not sure if you read my post correctly, however I know it already has a style to it, the style of the menu bar is however Horizontal. I am looking for a Vertical Menu bar similar to the link of Arkhams.

Comment: If you're having a horizontal menu in your snippet, well... that's not really help with all the non existent variables. And why not, for a start, just mimic the styles of your linked example?

Comment: @Felix Sorry... I'm not sure what you are proposing... I would really like a style as I showed and don't know how to do it :(

Comment: Your posted snippet doesn't work here. Missing CSS files, no access to the script variables etc. Now it shows a 500 server status. So if you want to illustrate something with it, then nobody can see it. However, if I get you right, you want to create a vertical menu as shown in the linked page. In that case take a look at their styles and use it as a starting point.

Comment: @Felix I apologize. The HTML you see creates this page: http://testingbuycrafttemp.buycraft.net/ 

I am trying to make it so that my menu bar goes vertical, pretty much just like the link I forward you to (Arkham's)

Comment: Take a look at the structure and layout you have, and and that you're aiming for. And move your your implementation towards that. If you have particular questions on parts of it, search them, then ask them. I'm not going to paste a complete solution for you. You wouldn't learn much, and it would nearly the same as your linked example. :)